# Is it possible to insert new card using mirror API to my APP in the Glass, and not to the main timeline?

Tags: google-mirror-api, gdk

I want to push card into my app in the Google Glass, and not to the timeline, my app in the glass contains cards with names of friends, I want to give ability to each one of the friends sending card under the friend name.

I will be happy to know if this behavior allowed, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends exactly what you mean. In general, it is best not to think about specific apps when it comes to Glass, but rather to think about actions that take place using Glass. So instead of "starting" an app that shows the names of each person, we might instead think about wanting to send a note to that person and have that person be on our contact list to get a note if we wish to send them one.

Doing it this way, your Glassware needs to create and maintain contacts and register them with the TAKE_A_NOTE action. See https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts for more details.

It isn't clear what you are trying to do exactly, but it sounds like you might be able to use card bundles as well. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/static-cards#bundling_cards to see if this scheme will work for you.

If you're not doing it either of these ways - you may need to update your initial question to clarify how you are starting and running the app itself and how you picture the entire workflow.